# use python pandas to show csv to placeholder in web file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file and need to convert it to view it in html. I know python pandas can do it with

```
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")
df.to_html('output.html')'
```

but I don't want to show it in single web page, I have index.html file and I want to show it in there but in another section.

Comment: one way it to use `.load ()` in jquery to load output.html into that section from index.html http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Use slice-row to get what you want for an `outputx.html`, for example, `df[10:21] will select rows 10 - 20.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer using tablib

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import tablib
import os

app = Flask (__name__)
dataset = tablib.Dataset()
with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'email.csv')) as f:
    dataset.csv = f.read()

@app.route("/")
def index():
    data = dataset.html
    #return dataset.html
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', 
    filename='css/style.css') }}"/>
    <title>Show CSV</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="table">
    {% block body %}
    {{ data|safe }}
    {% endblock %}  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```